# Диалоговое окно не правильно тображается

Tags: android, dialog

Вот так выглядит макет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вот так выглядит окно, при запуске

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="Please ajust Slideshow speed\nto make it the most comfortable\nfor you."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtTitle"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="Slideshow speed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/rbNormal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtMessage">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbSlow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="Slow"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbNormal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="Normal"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbFast"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="Fast"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOk"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="LAUNCH"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textColor="@color/color_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Вот сам код вызова DialogFragment

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_slideshow, container, false );
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что проблема во frame, в который вы этот фрагмент вставляете. Посмотрите(и нам тоже покажите) разметку того места, куда вставляется этот фрагмент. Скорее всего, контейнер сжат в углу

Comment: Добавьте код layout(a), поверх которого вы хотите отобразить ваш диалог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче помогло только это.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Window window=getDialog().getWindow();
    window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

Данный код в `onCreateView` не работает, только в `onResume`.

*

> *А есть ли способ, данную фишку использовать через XML, style манифест? а то как - то не очень смотриться, и почему в самом layout
>   не работает....*???

*